# A different view for Snapped state (Metro app)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a simple app I'm making and I am having a little trouble with the different states (Full, Snapped, etc).

Below, is how my app looks in landscape, full screen view. As you can see, it has 2 grids. One left aligned, and 1 right aligned:

[image]

Now, when the user snaps my app to the left or right, I want only the second grid (on the right: Grid TWO) to be visible in snapped mode, like this:

[image]

How can we achieve this?

I have tried several things but my current code doesn't work either. I know it's wrong but here it is anyway:

```
<!-- Back button and page title -->
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="120, 30, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox x:Name="theList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="240" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="theNote" Text="{Binding ElementName=theList, Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay}" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="245,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" />
</Grid>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

        <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Actually, your pictures appear to be showing *three* grids... Grid 1, Grid 2, and the main app grid with the back button and page title.  Your code snippet only shows 2 of these - the main app grid, and an unnamed grid below it.  If you're trying to manipulate either of these in your VisualStates, you'll need to give them name attributes.

Answer (score 1):

you need the following:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

You'll see that we're setting Grid1 to be hidden and Grid2 to be of a specific width.  This will happen when the page is moved to "Snapped" state.

Comment: Sorry @Faster Solutions - it just displays a blank screen (only app name and back button) when I put it in snapped view

Comment: @Faster Solutions:  In your code snippet there, you're setting the grid's Visibility property to a button style resource... probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in the visualstate = 'snapped'

```
           <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GridOne" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
```

Comment: Sorry @king - it just displays a blank screen (only app name and back button) when I put it in snapped view

Answer (score 0):

The second grid in your code snippet has a left margin of 120 pixels.  The text inside it has a left margin of 245 pixels, to place it to the right of the list.  Margins on nested objects will be additive, so the effective left margin for the text is 365 pixels (not even considering what else it's nested in).  Unless you are also changing these margin values when the page is placed in snapped view, the text will be too far to the right to see.  (Recall that snapped view is only 320 pixels wide!)

Here is a very simplified example of two grids on the page.  Note that Grid2 has a large left margin to place it on the right of Grid1.  The textboxes inside the grids have NO left margin.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="120,30,0,0" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox x:Name="theFirstNote" Text="This is grid 1." AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="370,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox x:Name="theSecondNote" Text="This is grid 2." AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>
```

When the VisualState changes to Snapped, not only do we have to change the visibility of Grid1, but we also have to change the margin of Grid2 so it's actually visible:

```
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
```